# cannot find symbol symbol: method location: class

Tags: java

Sorry, just learning Java; but, can someone tell me why I'm getting a "cannot find symbol" error?
My code is as follows:

```
public class NumberHolder {
  public int anInt;
  public float aFloat;

  public NumberHolder(int setAnInt, float setAFloat) {
    setAnInt = anInt;
    setAFloat = aFloat;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberHolder newNumber = NumberHolder(12, 24F);
  }
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a `new` before the call to the constructor:

```
NumberHolder newNumber = new NumberHolder(12, 24F);
```

EDIT:
Also, as Tassos Bassoukos points out in his answer, you need to turn around the assignments in the constructor:

```
anInt = setAnInt;
aFloat = setAFloat;
```

Although personally, I like to write my constructors like this:

```
public NumberHolder(int anInt, float aFloat) {
  this.anInt = anInt;
  this.aFloat = aFloat;
}
```

This is a matter of style and personal preference, though.

Comment: Duh. Thinking maybe I should sleep and try this tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: That's how I wrote it, but it was saying self assignment, and I changed it.

Comment: It's important to know that `this.anInt` refers to the field, but `anInt` refers to the parameter. So, the first one needs a `this.` in front of it, but the second one cannot have one, or else it won't work.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't entirely understand this. `this.anInt` refers to the field which is contained in the class, whereas `anInt` only refers to the parameter in your block?

Comment: Exactly :). The parameters "shadow" the fields with the same name, but by writing `this.` in front of them, you force the compiler to look at the containing class instead of the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Since

```
public NumberHolder(int anInt, float aFloat);
```

is a constructor and not an ordenary method, you need to use the keyword new in order to obtain the actual object. You are calling it like a method and you don't have any method named NumberHolder (but it would be valid if you'd have)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the `new` keyword that you're missing, the assignment in the constructor should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instanciate new objects with the `new` keyword.

```
public class NumberHolder {
    public int anInt;
    public float aFloat;

    public NumberHolder(int anInt, float aFloat) {
        this.anInt = anInt;
        this.aFloat = aFloat;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberHolder newNumber = new NumberHolder(12, 24F);
    }

}
```